# Codeigniter $this->db->select() not work with Round(Max()) or FORMAT(MAX())

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I  write following code

```
$this->db->select('SUM(qty) as total_qty,(FORMAT(SUM(amount),2)) as total_amount');
$this->db->where('Invoice_Rec_No',$Invoice_Rec_No);
$result=$this->db->get($this->invoice_products_tbl);
$total_data=$result->row();
```

but getting error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM (tbl_invoice_products) WHERE Invoice_Rec_No = 7' at line 2

SELECT SUM(qty) as total_qty, (FORMAT(SUM(amount), 2)) as total_amount FROM (tbl_invoice_products) WHERE Invoice_Rec_No = 7

Filename: C:\wamp\www\admin_followme247_master\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

I want to execute this query with codeigniter ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 3):

User second parameter `FALSE` in db `select` method

```
    $this->db->select('SUM(qty) as total_qty,
                       (FORMAT(SUM(amount),2)) as total_amount', FALSE);
```

CI db class is automatic add `(apostrophe) when manipulate sql query, if you pass send parameter`FALSE`in`select` method then it is keep same as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your code like this

```
$select = array(
    'SUM(qty) as total_qty',
    '(FORMAT(SUM(amount),2)) as total_amount'
);
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->where('Invoice_Rec_No',$Invoice_Rec_No);
$result=$this->db->get($this->invoice_products_tbl);
$total_data=$result->row();
```

For simple column selection it is fine to use string but for complex selection like this one you can either use an array or select each column separately